# How to get USA states dropdown list magento2 custom phtml

Tags: magento2, custom, state

I need to display the all the USA states as a select drop-down in magento2 custom phtml. Can anyone help me.

Comment: Are you use custom module?

Comment: Yes, using the custom module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following code in your block class

```
<?php
    ...

    private $directoryData;

    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Directory\Block\Data $directoryData
        ...
    ) {
        ...
        $this->directoryData = $directoryData;
        ...
    }

    public function getStates()
    {
        return $this->directoryData->getRegionHtmlSelect();
    }
}
```

Add following code in your PHTML file

```
<?php

echo $block->getStates();
```

**Extra Notes:**

You can use following code to get the complete data.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$states = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory')
        ->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('country_id','US');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($states->getData());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$regionFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory')->create();
$regionFactory->addFieldToFilter('country_id', array('eq' => 'US'));
echo '<pre>';print_r($regionFactory->getData());
```

Also if you can directly call default magento country and state drop down in your custom phtml file, Here is link may be it's help full.
https://magebug.blogspot.in/2018/04/magento-2-how-to-display-country.html