# How to show state dropdown in phtml file in magento2

Tags: magento2, blocks, country-regions

I want to show state drop down in phtml file in magento2

I have a country code

```
<?php $countryBlock = $block->getLayout()- 
 >createBlock('Magento\Directory\Block\Data');?>
            <?= $countryBlock->getCountryHtmlSelect($defValue = null, 
  $name = 'country_id', $id = 'country', $title = 'Country');?>
```

this shows the country name now i want to show state name also

Comment: You can follow this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224437/how-to-get-usa-states-dropdown-list-magento2-custom-phtml?rq=1

Comment: This link helped me when i worked on it: https://magecomp.com/blog/create-country-state-dropdown-in-magento-2-custom-frontend-form/